# Why is permute needed in parallel SIMD/SSE/AVX ?

Tags: permutation, sse, simd, avx

From my other question about ["Using SIMD AVX SSE for tree traversal"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616605/using-simd-avx-sse-for-tree-traversal) ive got this code that im trying to benchmark. I havent done anything with SIMD before so I'm kinda new to this permutation stuff. First, lets see this code:

```
__m256i const perm_mask = _mm256_set_epi32(7, 6, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 0);

// compare the two halves of the cache line.
__m256i cmp1 = _mm256_load_si256(&node->m256[0]);
__m256i cmp2 = _mm256_load_si256(&node->m256[1]);

cmp1 = _mm256_cmpgt_epi32(cmp1, value); // PCMPGTD
cmp2 = _mm256_cmpgt_epi32(cmp2, value); // PCMPGTD

// merge the comparisons back together.
//
// a permute is required to get the pack results back into order
// because AVX-256 introduced that unfortunate two-lane interleave.
//
// alternately, you could pre-process your data to remove the need
// for the permute.
__m256i cmp = _mm256_packs_epi32(cmp1, cmp2); // PACKSSDW
cmp = _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32(cmp, perm_mask); // PERMD

// finally create a move mask and count trailing
// zeroes to get an index to the next node.

unsigned mask = _mm256_movemask_epi8(cmp); // PMOVMSKB
return _tzcnt_u32(mask) / 2; // TZCNT
```

The author, [Cory Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209199/cory-nelson) tried to explain it with the comments. However, I'm not really getting how this permutations work and why it does end up to "extract" the wanted information from the result vector.

Could anybody help me out to understand how the permutation, movemask an TZCNT is used in this code and what "packing/unpacking" means in this context ? I'd be thankfull for any resources you might have about it - google aint that helpfull with this very special topic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Intel's [instruction set manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) will be invaluable to your learning of SIMD. It explains in great detail what each of those instructions is doing.

"Packing" in SSE/AVX is basically a downcast and merge of two registers. `PACKSSDW` packs 32-bit signed ints from two registers into 16-bit signed ints in one register, and saturates the values (so values < -32768 will be set to -32768, and >32767 will be set to 32767)

A permute is a way of reordering the values in a register. Each value in the mask register specifies an index into the source. This is required because AVX256 "cheated" a little and processes most of its mixing instructions as two 128-bit "lanes".

The 128-bit version of PACKSSDW performs this:

```
r0 := SignedSaturate(a0)
r1 := SignedSaturate(a1)
r2 := SignedSaturate(a2)
r3 := SignedSaturate(a3)
r4 := SignedSaturate(b0)
r5 := SignedSaturate(b1)
r6 := SignedSaturate(b2)
r7 := SignedSaturate(b3)
```

You'd expect the 256-bit version to maintain the same natural ordering with all the "A"s first and the "B"s second, like this:

```
r0 := SignedSaturate(a0)
r1 := SignedSaturate(a1)
r2 := SignedSaturate(a2)
r3 := SignedSaturate(a3)
r4 := SignedSaturate(a4)
r5 := SignedSaturate(a5)
r6 := SignedSaturate(a6)
r7 := SignedSaturate(a7)
r8 := SignedSaturate(b0)
r9 := SignedSaturate(b1)
r10 := SignedSaturate(b2)
r11 := SignedSaturate(b3)
r12 := SignedSaturate(b4)
r13 := SignedSaturate(b5)
r14 := SignedSaturate(b6)
r15 := SignedSaturate(b7)
```

But instead, what it actually does this:

```
r0 := SignedSaturate(a0) // lane one, the low 128 bits.
r1 := SignedSaturate(a1)
r2 := SignedSaturate(a2)
r3 := SignedSaturate(a3)
r4 := SignedSaturate(b0)
r5 := SignedSaturate(b1)
r6 := SignedSaturate(b2)
r7 := SignedSaturate(b3)
r8 := SignedSaturate(a4) // lane two, the high 128 bits.
r9 := SignedSaturate(a5)
r10 := SignedSaturate(a6)
r11 := SignedSaturate(a7)
r12 := SignedSaturate(b4)
r13 := SignedSaturate(b5)
r14 := SignedSaturate(b6)
r15 := SignedSaturate(b7)
```

The result is that when comparing an array of neatly ordered values, the 128-bit version keeps them ordered while the 256-bit version will mix them. The permute puts them back into order.

As I alluded to in my post, you can get rid of the permute in this code by preprocessing your node's array to have the inverse, so that the "mixed" results of the 256-bit op puts it back in order:

```
void preprocess_avx2(bnode* const node)
{
    __m256i const perm_mask = _mm256_set_epi32(3, 2, 1, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4);
    __m256i *const middle = (__m256i*)&node->i32[4];

    __m256i x = _mm256_loadu_si256(middle);
    x = _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32(x, perm_mask);
    _mm256_storeu_si256(middle, x);
}
```

The ordering is important because of what it does next.

The compare works on 16 32-bit values, but it results in either 0x0000 or 0xFFFF for all of them. You essentially only have 16 bits of information -- off or on for each value. `PMOVMSKB` treats the input as 32 8-byte values and packs the high bits of each (which is all we need, since all the bits are the same) into a 32-bit `int`.

`TZCNT` counts the trailing zero bits in that `int`, which gives an index to the first position that has a set bit: the index of the first byte in that SIMD register that compared as greater-than.

(Fun fact: `TZCNT` is a Haswell improvement over the existing `BSF` instruction, and in fact shares an encoding with it. The only difference is that `TZCNT` has a defined register output when its input is `0` -- with `BSF` you'd need to branch.)

Comment: The second part is clear to me now. However I dont really understand the deeper reason for them to mix it up the two 128 bit chunks - do you know why they have done it that way? For me it seems to be natural, that one wants a fully non-mixed 256 bit interval of bits.

Comment: It was likely a decision to save space on the CPU. This way they could get away with only implementing a 128-bit version, and having the 256-bit version just get split into two 128-bit µops.

Comment: Thank you! I think i've got the full coverage of understanding now. Very helpfull answer :-) Its more about understanding than performance optimiziation - as it already pwns!

Comment: `pack*` instructions move data opposite of how `unpck` instructions interleave.  @CoryNelson: The execution units in Intel's CPUs actually are 256bits wide, but it saves on wires and connections if each 128b can be implemented separately, instead of needing connections from every byte to all 31 other bytes.  (AMD actually did keep their execution units 128b wide, so 256b AVX instructions are twice as many ops, and twice the cycles.)