# Why is it impossible to find a specified value in a sorted array faster than O(log n)?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm pretty new to computer science. In the closing to a lecture, my AP Computer Science teacher mentioned the comparison model for finding a specified value in a sorted array is *big omega (log n)* i.e. **Ω(log n)**, which as I understand it, means it’s impossible to accomplish this task any faster than **O(log n)**. Why is this?

Comment: You can find a value in a sorted array using binary chops. But to make it faster, you need to do it in `O(1)` which...you cannot without knowing where that value is. To know where the value is, you need to search the array.

Comment: @VLAZ There are runtimes that are smaller than O(log n) but bigger than O(1), and it's possible to search arrays in those runtimes. For example, a fusion tree lets you do searches in time O(log n / log w), where w is the computer's word size.

Comment: There are sorted data structures faster than arrays. If I know the machine cache line size I can make it much faster.

Comment: do any of these help? https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-complexity?tab=Votes

Comment: @templatetypedef unless you have a computer with an unbounded and variable word size, that's exactly the same as O(log n)

Comment: > '"big omega (log n)" […] means it’s impossible to accomplish this task any faster than O(log n)'—no, that's not what this means. Being Ω(log n) is a property of a mathematical function. It's not a property of an algorithm (though it may be a property of an algorithm's worst/best/average/expected-case runtime) or a problem (though it may be a property of the worst/best/average/expected-case runtimes of all solutions to that problem).

Comment: As a minor clarification: an algorithm classified as O(log n) *might* finish in less than O(log n) time, it will certainly finish in at *most* O(log n) time.

O(log n) is a measure of the worst case.

Comment: You could have a sorted array implemented as an array where `i` is presente if `array[i]==true`. Then to decide if `i` is present all you would need to do is check `array[i]` (O(1)). But that would be **very** impractical in terms of memory and of functionality.

Comment: It is of course possible to find it faster. This is a probability. However we should consider the pessimum outcomes.  There is never a guarantee that it will not be found immediately say.    "At most" matters, as does the distribution.  It matters in programming where we need to know the T cycles.  It takes at most 13 clocks to find an analog value to 10 bits in an ATMega328P,  at 20MHz that is enough wriggle room for 1 million samples a second, but they will not all take 13 cycles.

Comment: It's not impossible. If for example you know that the values in the array are dense in the integer space, you can do it in *O(1).* Not very useful, but possible.

Comment: Bogosort could potentially find your value instantly, and potentially never.

Answer (score 120):

Let's imagine that you have an array of n items. If you perform a lookup in this array, then that lookup can return one of n + 1 values: either "the item isn't present," or "the item is present at index i" for any of the n indices.

Now, suppose that the only way that your algorithm is allowed to work with the array is by asking questions of the form "is the item greater than or equal to the item in index i?" for some choice of i, and let's imagine that you ask some question of this form k total times. There are then 2<sup>k</sup> possible ways that the comparisons could come back. To see why, there are two options for the how the first comparison can go (either "yes" or "no"). There are two options for how the second comparison can go (either "yes" or "no"), and two options for the third comparison. Multiplying all those 2s together gives 2<sup>k</sup>.

We now have two constraints:

1. Any correct algorithm must be able to return one of n + 1 different options.
2. With k comparisons, there are 2<sup>k</sup> possible ways those comparisons can work out.

This means that we have to have n + 1 ≤ 2<sup>k</sup>, since otherwise there aren't enough possible outcomes from the search algorithm to be able to cover all n + 1 possible outcomes. Taking the log base two of both sides gives lg (n + 1) ≤ k, so the number of comparisons made must be Ω(log n).

Stated differently - if your algorithm makes too few queries, there aren't enough possible ways for those comparisons to go to ensure that every possible option can be produced.

---

Of course, if you aren't in the comparison model, you can outperform searches in an array using hash tables. Some hash tables give expected O(1) lookups, while others (say, cuckoo hashing) give worst-case O(1) lookups.

Moving outside the comparison model, there are algorithms that, subject to certain assumptions, have expected runtimes lower than O(log n). For example, [interpolation search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) can find items in sorted arrays in expected time O(log log n), provided that the data are sampled from a uniform distribution. It works by making numeric estimates of where in the sequence to choose the next item to probe, and works well in practice.

On the more theoretical side of things, [fusion trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_tree) can perform searches in time O(log n / log w), where w is the machine word size, provided that the values are integers that fit into a single machine word. This can be improved down to the surprising runtime of O(sqrt(log n / log log n)). It's known that if the n values each fit into a single machine word, then the [predecessor lower bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predecessor_problem) says you can't do better than the (very unusual runtime of) O(min{log w / log log w, sqrt(log n / log log n)}), where w is the machine word size. These algorithms outperform the Ω(log n) lower bound by making multiple comparisons in parallel using creative operations on individual machine words.

Comment: That is a _brilliant_ explanation. Basically the Pidgeonhole principle.

Comment: I think this answer is missing information about *why* binary search, where the upper limit is log(n+1) comparisions, is the best one and it's *impossible* to have anything better. The equation n+1 <= 2^k is obviously correct for binary search but "let's imagine that you ask some question of this form k total times" is not good enough for universal explanation. The answer is related to available data (only ordered array with no memory of any kind nor knowledge of distribution of values) but that's much harder to have a proof.

Comment: Interpolation search works faster by *assuming* even distribution of data and Fusion trees are not simple arrays so that's not an answer for this question.

Comment: I you need to search for specified values often and you can use extra memory, it's better to create a hash map which should take about O(n) to create and you then need O(1) to query each value. The interesting question is where do you get the sorted array? Could the source of the data be changed to return the same data in some other format?

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen note the question assumes we are in the comparison model.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen neither the question nor the answer mentions binary search, nor do they require it. It holds for any search algorithm of a general sorted array.

Comment: If we're willing to entertain "certain assumptions" it may be worth noting that you can find a specified value in O(1) because you remember where you put it. O(log n) is the answer to the question asked. Not every possible kind of search.

Comment: @ArtimisFowl: yes, the question mentioned  comparison model. However, if you pretend that `k` is not result of binary search, the explanation that n+1 <= 2^k doesn't actually mean anything. I think it could be reformatted as a proper proof by explaining why 2^k is the minimum amount of comparisions in worst case and then pointing out that binary search can accomplish this. That wouldn't need formulations such as "let's imagine that you ask some question of this form k total times".

Comment: I think the answer is in information theory. For `n` times, you need at least `lg n` bits of information to uniquely identify any one item. You can think of the questions you ask during the search as "is bit `k` of the label 0 or 1?" Fewer than `lg n` questions can't give you information about all `lg n` bits, because they are independent of each other.

Comment: @chepner Yep, exactly. The way I'm framing it here avoids talking about bits, since I wasn't sure whether the OP was familiar with the idea of writing out bits of the index.

Comment: re: fusion trees: in a more realistic model of performance cost, cache lines are the granularity that matters; if you read one word of a line, you might as well read them all.  And instead of packing more values into the bits of one word, just use SIMD compares to let you check 16 `int32_t` .  [What is the most efficient way to implement a BST in such a way the find(value) function is optimized for random values in the tree on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56614414) discusses that (using implicit trees instead of actual pointers).  But unless you need ordered traversal, use a hash table

Comment: I don't think interpolation search is within the comparison model as this answer suggests. Even though it does make comparisons, it also uses the numeric values of the keys it encounters to make a guess about the best element to compare with next, and in doing so, it goes outside the comparison model.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Good point - I hadn’t thought of that. Let me fix that…

Answer (score 15):

To start with be careful about using the word "faster" when talking about Big-O complexity as it's done in the question title. Big-O says nothing about how fast an algorithm is. Big-O only tells how execution time changes when some variable N changes. Example:

```
O(1) algorithm   : Doubling N will not change execution time
O(N) algorithm   : Doubling N will double execution time (1 + 1 = 2) 
O(N^2) algorithm : Doubling N will quadruple execution time (2 * 2 = 4)
```

Also notice that for some N values a O(N^2) algorithm may be faster than an O(N) algorithm. Big-O doesn't tell anything about that. All we can say is that if we keep increasing N then sooner or later the O(N) algorithm will be faster than the O(N^2) algorithm. But Big-O doesn't tell what that value of N is. It can be for N=1, N=10, N=100, ... So be careful about "translating" Big-O complexity into "fast".

Big-O is calculated as the number of times you need to perform some basic operation (an O(1) operation) as function of the variable N. Further, Big-O (normally) looks at worst case scenarios.

For an ordinary array the only basic operation we can perform is to look-up the value at some index `i` in the range 1..N

In a sorted array the returned value can be used to tell us three things (see later paragraph for exceptions):

1. Is the value less than the value we are searching for
2. Is the value greater than the value we are searching for
3. Is the value equal to the value we are searching for

Now remember that Big-O is about worst case scenarious. So number 3 won't happen unless we are looking in a range with only one array element. So forget about number 3 for now.

Because the array is sorted the relevant answers can be translated into

1. The search value is in range 1 .. `i`
2. The search value is in range `i`+1 .. N

Now the question is: How to select the best value of `i` for the first look up?

Since Big-O is a worst case calculation, we shall always use the largest of the two ranges for the next step. To make the largest range as small as possible, we need to make the two ranges the same size. To do that we need `i` to be equal N/2. **This is simply the best we can do with the knowledge we have from the look-up**.

By doing that we have

1. The search value is in range 1 .. N/2
2. The search value is in range N/2+1 .. N

So in the next step we need to look in a range with N/2 elements.

Now apply the same again (i.e. `i` = N/2/2) for the next search to get down to N/4 element. Do it again to get to N/8 elements and so...

Repeat that until there is 1 element in the range - then we have the solution (number 3 above).

So each look-up reduce the range into half of it's original size. And `k` look-up will reduce the range by `2^k`. Our target is to get a range size of 1 so we need to solve:

N / 2^k = 1 <=> N = 2^K <=> K = log<sub>2</sub>(N)

So from the **assumption that all we can know from a look-up is whether our search value is to the left or right of the look-up position** and from the fact that Big-O is worst case calculated, we can see that the search in a sorted array can't be any better than log(N) complexity.

The above covers the general array but notice that for some arrays the assumption may not hold. Sometimes an algorithm may extract more information from the look-up'ed value at index `i`. For instance if we know something about the distribution of values in the array and our search value is far from the look-up value, an algorithm may benefit from doing something else in the next look-up than doing the next look-up at N/2 and thereby be more efficient.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an "at most" when describing the change of execution-time for doubling problem-size?

Comment: @Deduplicator As far as I know there shouldn't be an "at most". Except from some special cases (especially sorting algos), Big-O only cares about worst-case. Further Big-O don't care out "minor" details... All noise is removed. Examples. O(10*N) is stil O(N). O(N^2 + 10N) is still O(N^2). So whether the actual execution time becomes at little less or a little more than Big-O says, doesn't mather. Big-O is (AFAIK) only about the trend - not the details. If I'm wrong, please let me know. Thanks - and thanks for you reply, I appricate your feedback.

Comment: Big-Oh gives an upper bound, but not necessarily a tight one, which would also be a lower bound. Thus, Anything O(n) is O(n²), but much of O(n²) is not O(n).

Answer (score 5):

If you do not know preliminary info about keys distribution, really, your search is O(log(n)), because of each comparison you extract 1 bit if information, and reduce search area twice.
But, for practical cases, you can search in sorted array much fastest. Fro instance, see the [Interpolation search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search), it is just O(log(log(n))).

Comment: Good thing to mention interpolation search, but "for practical cases" is a *massive* overstatement. Most datasets do not come with a guaranteed approximate distribution.

Comment: Interpolation is, in fact, O(n). It's O(log(log(n))) only in a special case of uniformly distributed and sorted data.

Comment: @Davor You can make interpolation search worst-case efficient by counting how many steps you’ve taken and, if it exceeds log n, stopping the interpolation bit and switching to binary search over the remaining range. Basically, do the fast approach, except that if it looks like it’s slowing down, switch to something you know for a fact will be fast.

Answer (score 2):

**The running time of an algorithm cannot be less than the size of its output**, because at the very least it has to write that output. Here, the output of an algorithm which searches a value in a sorted array is the index of the value found in the array (even if your actual algorithm produces something different, it would still have to determine that index internally). It is an integer between 0 and the number N of items of the array.

**Encoding a value among N possible values requires a worst-case size of Ω(log(N)).** Indeed, let’s say you have an alphabet of two symbols: 0 and 1. There are 2<sup>k</sup> strings of length k, and there are 1 + 2 + 2<sup>2</sup> + … + 2<sup>k−1</sup> = 2<sup>k</sup>−1 strings of length strictly less than k. Hence, if you want an encoding for N = 2<sup>k</sup> (or more) distinct values, it is not possible that all values are encoded with less than k symbols. Necessarily, at least one of them will be encoded with at least k symbols. So your worst-case size is an Ω(k) = Ω(log(N)).

For instance, to write any integer between 0 and 2<sup>16</sup>, you need 16 binary digits.

A larger alphabet does not increase your expressive power. It only changes a constant factor, which is hidden by the asymptotic notations.

To conclude, the output is a value that you need to tell apart among N possible values, and for that you need Ω(log(N)) symbols in the worst case.

**A remark:** if you use two symbols (i.e. write integers in binary), and N = 2<sup>k</sup> (to simplify), then the dichotomic search algorithm that you surely know (or will know very soon) consists exactly in determining the k symbols (bits) of the output one by one, from the most significant bit to the least significant bit.

Comment: This sounds good, but doesn't really match the RAM machine model typically used for algorithmic analysis (where sizes are measured in machine words, and the number of bits in a machine word scales with the logarithm of the input size). If you want to use a different model where writing a single number takes longer than O(1) time, then you also have to consider factors like how long it takes to read an input element, or how long it takes to perform a comparison, or how the input is encoded in the first place, and you're likely to end up with a runtime other than O(log(n)).

Comment: Did you mean Ω(·) rather than O(·) ? For proving a lower bound, we can ignore some operations, only the bound might not be tight.
/ Machine words are simply a larger alphabet, which (as you said) still scales logarithmically, isn’t it? If integers have constant size, then integers are bounded, memory is finite, and complexity speeches aren’t really sound as there is no asymptotic behavior to reason about at all.
/ The question seemed to be about learning complexity theory, so I went for that. Indeed, in such a model, the optimal running time will likely be larger than the expected Θ(log(N)).

Comment: It sounds like you may not be familiar with the RAM machine model - you may want to go look that up. If you want to use a model where you cannot operate on indexes in constant time, then that's likely to be a model where there is no equivalent of array indexing at all - for example, a Turing machine, where you have to move along the tape one cell at a time. In that case, you can't do any better than a linear scan of the input. This just isn't a very useful model for complexity theory, since it's so far from how we perform computation in practice.

Comment: (Actually, looking it up myself, it looks like the RAM machine model is usually formulated with registers holding arbitrary integers, rather than with machine words scaling with the logarithm of the input size. I may have been thinking of a variant, like the [transdichotomous model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transdichotomous_model).)

Comment: “It sounds like you may not be familiar with the RAM machine model” I’ll have to admit that. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: "The running time of an algorithm cannot be less than the size of its output".  Confusing time with space seems inappropriate to me.

Comment: The size of the output is 1 in this case. It's a single integer. The algorithm takes time to *compute* that integer. And how long that takes depends on the number of elements in the array, not the length of the integer. Your argument would require a hash table lookup to be O(log(n)), rather than O(1), because it also returns an index or pointer or whatever.

Comment: If you assume it takes O(log n) time to do integer operations, then binary search would take O(log^2 n) time, because of the arithmetic and comparison operations in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The only info we have is it's sorted. Let's say we are in the middle of the array now you make a decision based on **1 comparison** that if the left half has the answer or the right half has the answer or mid itself is the answer and the recursively doing the comparison till we find the element ...
The point to note here is that you are able to do so is because the array is sorted now let assume we are standing at some random point now still you can apply the same algorithm but you might partition the array unevenly which might screw up your number of comparison. Let say your random point is always at starting or ending point of the array the algo will have the complexity of O(N) in the worst-case. So, The best way to search for an element in the next recursion call is to reduce the search space by half each time which you are able to do in only 1 comparison, now you cannot decide this in less than 1 comparison unless there is some kind of pre-processing done which will again take more than O(log(N)

Comment: Another way of saying it is that you need to be able to identify one of N different items, using an operation that only yields one bit of information about its identity.  If the basic operation one performs can yield more than one bit of information about an object's identity, as would be the case with a hash table, or if one wouldn't need to *uniquely* identify the object, adequate identification may require fewer operations.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually very easy to understand.

In the beginning, the search space is the whole array. Clearly, the quicker you minimize the search space…

- The quicker your search for the target value will finish; and,
- The better time complexity you have achieved.

In simpler words, if after first step you are able to reduce the search space from n/2 (in case of binary search) to n<sup>1/2</sup> or something else smaller than n/2, then you have provably achieved a lower search complexity.

---

Instead of going by your professor’s wisdom and inspecting the mid value, let’s say you start your search by inspecting a value greater than mid value in every iteration. Now, if your target value is smaller than mid, you will end up with a search space larger than n/2 with your approach.

You have already seen that when you split the search space in half by employing binary search, you get a Log(n) complexity. There is no way that your search will finish faster than Log(n) if you are ending with search spaces larger than half of the array in each iteration. And that is why you cannot do better than Log(n) when searching a sorted array using a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

Take an array of N items, sorted into order. You start by picking the middle item and seeing if it is bigger or smaller than your target. Now you know which half of the array your target is in. So you repeat the process with N/2 item, pick the middle item, etc. So you go N/4, N/8 .... until you get down to a single item.

How many steps does it take to get to that single item? Well if the array has 1 item then its 0 steps. 2 items takes 1 step. 4 items 2 steps, 8 items 3 steps, and so on. Log2(8) = 3, log2(16) = 4, and so on. Now do you see?

Comment: This accounts for why O(log n) is possible, but it doesn't address why O(log n) is the limit for comparison sorting. How do you know that you can't improve upon this?

Answer (score -4):

It can be done in O(1) if you use O(N) processors.

But I guess that's outside what your teacher considered solution space.

Comment: How can you do it in O(1)? You still need to merge results which will take O(log n) time.

Comment: This is a bit like saying if you have a unicorn then you can fly to a magic land in O(1) time to find a wizard who tells you the answer. It's true within your fiction, but it's not relevant to the question. No computer in the real world has an arbitrarily large number of processors, and the theoretical models actually used by computer scientists would not assume this.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka each processor gets addres of begining, knows its offset and adress of result. If it's begining+offset == number write into result your offset.

Comment: @kaya3 processor use only constant time ammount of silicon than memory for one variable. therefore it is as possible as unbounded memory (i mean both impossible). I agree that my O(1) solution is highly impractical, but someone with more experience can maybe find some that requires eg. O(log(n)) processors and gives wall time better than O(log(n)).

Comment: @Alpedar propagation of write and synchronization will take a logarithmic time in number of processors over the network at best.

Comment: This isn't even really O(1), it's O(n), it's just that you are doing all n operations in parallel, giving the appearance of O(1). (I'm sure we could do similar tricks to do O(log n) operations faster, at the expense of lesser hardware than O(n) processors.)