# SIMD Instructions to accelerate search for matching values between two sorted int Arrays, for a Hadamard Product

Tags: algorithm, f#, intersection, simd, avx

I am trying to implement the fastest possible join of two datasets and taking the product of the values when the indices match. I have a scalar approach to this but I believe using SIMD I can accelerate this algorithm. I have two `Span<int>` which are the keys that must match to take the product: `aKeys` and `bKeys`. Where the value in `aKeys` matches the value in `bKeys`, the corresponding values in `aValues` and `bValues` should be multiplied and stored.

I am looking to use SIMD instruction to be able to compare a single key from `aKeys` to many values in `bKeys`. The trick is that once the values for `bKeys` are greater than the `aKey` value I am testing, I need to move to the next `aKey` value. This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68878740/using-f-and-simd-to-search-for-index-of-value). A full example with benchmark code can be found in [this repo](https://github.com/matthewcrews/HadamardProductSIMD).

The algorithm for `IndexOf<T>` in [SpanHelpers](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/a9f3fc16483eecfc47fb79c362811d870be02249/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/SpanHelpers.Char.cs#L221) is close but it is only for looking up a single value. I'm trying to take advantage of the fact that I have several values to lookup, all unique and in ascending order.

```ml
// NOTE: The length of aKeys and aValues is the same.
// The length of bKeys and bValues is the same.
// The values in `aKeys` and `bKeys` are unique and sorted but not every value
// in aKeys will be present in bKeys and vice versa.

let hadamardProduct (aKeys: Span<int>, aValues: Span<float>, bKeys: Span<int>, bValues: Span<float>) =
    let maxN = Math.Min (aKeys.Length, bKeys.Length)
    let outKeys = Array.zeroCreate maxN
    let outValues = Array.zeroCreate maxN

    let mutable aIdx = 0
    let mutable bIdx = 0
    let mutable outIdx = 0

    while aIdx < aKeys.Length && bIdx < bKeys.Length do
        
        if aKeys.[aIdx] = bKeys.[bIdx] then
            outKeys.[outIdx] <- aKeys.[aIdx]
            outValues.[outIdx] <- aValues.[aIdx] * bValues.[bIdx]
            outIdx <- outIdx + 1
            aIdx <- aIdx + 1
            bIdx <- bIdx + 1
        elif aKeys.[aIdx] < bKeys.[bIdx] then
            aIdx <- aIdx + 1
        else
            bIdx <- bIdx + 1

    let resultKeys = Memory (outKeys, 0, outIdx)
    let resultValues = Memory (outValues, 0, outIdx)

    resultKeys, resultValues
```

**UPDATE 2021-08-23 09:26**

After working on this some more I have now come up with the following approach. I am curious if there is anything to be done to make the code go faster?

```ml
#nowarn "9" "51" "20" // Don't want warnings about pointers

open System
open FSharp.NativeInterop
open System.Numerics
open System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86
open System.Runtime.Intrinsics

let hadamardProduct (aKeys: Span<int>, aValues: Span<float>, bKeys: Span<int>, bValues: Span<float>) =
    let maxN = Math.Min (aKeys.Length, bKeys.Length)
    let outKeys = Array.zeroCreate maxN
    let outValues = Array.zeroCreate maxN

    let mutable aIdx = 0
    let mutable bIdx = 0
    let mutable outIdx = 0

    if bKeys.Length > 4 then

        let lastBlockIdx = bKeys.Length - (bKeys.Length % 4)
        let bPointer = && (bKeys.GetPinnableReference ())
        let mutable bVector = Sse2.LoadVector128 (NativePtr.add bPointer bIdx)

        while aIdx < aKeys.Length && bIdx < lastBlockIdx do
            let aVector = Vector128.Create aKeys.[aIdx]
            let comparison = Sse2.CompareEqual (aVector, bVector)
            let matches = Sse2.MoveMask (comparison.AsByte ())

            if matches > 0 then
                let bIdxOffset = (BitOperations.TrailingZeroCount matches) / 4 // Convert byte offset to index
                outKeys.[outIdx] <- aKeys.[aIdx]
                outValues.[outIdx] <- aValues.[aIdx] * bValues.[bIdx + bIdxOffset]
                aIdx <- aIdx + 1
                outIdx <- outIdx + 1
                // REMEMBER, bIdx is testing 4 values at a time so we don't always want to jump

            elif aKeys.[aIdx] > bKeys.[bIdx + 3] then
                // REMEMBER!! bIdx needs to stride, not increment
                bIdx <- bIdx + 4
                // We only want to load new values when necessary
                if bIdx < lastBlockIdx then
                    bVector <- Sse2.LoadVector128 (NativePtr.add bPointer bIdx)
            else
                aIdx <- aIdx + 1

    // Final pass for data that didn't fit the Vector128 size
    while aIdx < aKeys.Length && bIdx < bKeys.Length do
        
        if aKeys.[aIdx] = bKeys.[bIdx] then
            outKeys.[outIdx] <- aKeys.[aIdx]
            outValues.[outIdx] <- aValues.[aIdx] * bValues.[bIdx]
            outIdx <- outIdx + 1
            aIdx <- aIdx + 1
            bIdx <- bIdx + 1
        elif aKeys.[aIdx] < bKeys.[bIdx] then
            aIdx <- aIdx + 1
        else
            bIdx <- bIdx + 1

    let resultKeys = Memory (outKeys, 0, outIdx)
    let resultValues = Memory (outValues, 0, outIdx)

    resultKeys, resultValues
```

Comment: Have you considered CUDAS for implementing this?

Comment: CUDAS, please define.

Comment: CUDA, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA Unified architecture for GPUs.  Commonly used for machine learning but it's all about matrix multiplication.  See https://github.com/DeepMLNet/Tensor.Sample/blob/master/Program.fs.  It's not going to get faster than using a GPU.

Comment: I am aware of CUDA. I think the overhead of moving memory back and forth from the GPU would not be worth it in this case though. If someone showed me a benchmark that proved otherwise, I would change my mind.

Comment: did you profile it? is there data alignment and is it satisfied? (cool question btw)

Comment: I did profile. You can see the benchmarks here: https://github.com/matthewcrews/HadamardProductSIMD. I don't know enough yet to evaluate the data alignment. I'm still learning.